# Why can't I seem to pass a variable from a controller to a form in symfony 4?

Tags: symfony

So I am trying to pass a variable to a form from my controller in a Symfony 4.3 project... I have tried to set the options resolver, pass arrays... Im still getting no luck and the 'option "0" does not exist....'

define the variable in configureOptions as  setDefaults and setRequired
pass an array () type from the controller in the createForm(ThingType::class, $thing, array ('my_option' => $myOption)

from the controller :

`$form = $this->createForm(PieceEditType::class, $piece, ['pieceId'=> $piece->getId()]);`

from the form side :

```
    * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
    * @param array $options
    *
    */
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {

      $pieceId = $options['pieceId'];

       $builder
           ->add('full', FileType::class, [
               'data_class' => null

           ])
          ->add('ordering', EntityType::class, [
              'class' =>Image::class,
               'choice_label' => 'ordering',
               'query_builder' => function (ImageRepository $er){
                   return $er->findByPieceAndReturnOrdered($pieceId);

               }
          ])


       ;
   }

   /**
    * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => Image::class,
           'pieceId' => null,
       ));
       $resolver->setRequired([
           'pieceId',

       ]);


   }
```

So just trying to pass a pieceId to the form for its own querybuilder so it populates the select with just what I need it to populate it with.

instead, error   'The option "0" (or "pieceId" ) does not exist. Defined options are etc etc'

Comment: Looks right. Try clearing the cache... `bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: looks right +... Working, if delete the `$resolver->setRequired` part from the `configureOptions`?

Comment: Nope, tried that too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I eventually got it straightened up. Two things :

- I forgot to mention was that this form type was an embedded child of a parent form : so I had to set the variable as default options in the same way, but upstream, then pass it as one custom index of the parameters array entry_options of CollectionType.

```
class PieceEditType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $pieceId = $options['pieceId'];

$builder
            ->add('images', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type'=> ImagesEditType::class,

                'allow_add' =>true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' =>false,
                'entry_options' => ['pieceId' => $pieceId,'label'=>false],

            ])
       ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Piece::class,
            'pieceId'=> null,
        ]);
    }
```

From there, the variable was passed to the child form without a change in the code (the error was just upstream).

Child form :

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $test = $options['pieceId'];

$builder
           ->add('ordering', EntityType::class, [
               'class' =>Image::class,
                'choice_label' => 'ordering',
                'query_builder' => function (ImageRepository $er) use ($test){
                    return $er->findByPieceAndReturnOrdered($test);

                }
           ])
}
     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefaults(
            ['data_class' => Image::class,
                'pieceId' => null,
            ]
        );        $definedOptions = $resolver->getDefinedOptions();
        dump($definedOptions);
        $resolver->setDefined('pieceId');
        $resolver->setRequired(['pieceId']);

    }
}
```

- Once the variable was hydrating the child form, the repository method called from the query_builder parameter would make the form throw a format error (the 'array given' sorta thing) : the reason was, since this was an existing method in the repository, called by other controllers, it contained ->getQuery()  and ->getResult() querybuilder sub-methods, where breaking the form.

```
    public function findByPieceAndReturnOrdered($pieceId)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->andWhere('i.Piece = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $pieceId)
            ->orderBy('i.ordering', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

So I ended up writing a dedicated query function, right in the formtype, like a very lazy person, which allowed my form to finally be rendered.

```
                'query_builder' => function (ImageRepository $er) use ($test){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->andWhere('u.Piece = :val')
                        ->setParameter('val', $test)
                        ->orderBy('u.ordering', 'ASC')

;
```

The getQuery() and getResult() just needed to be removed. Child form likes his queries with no training wheels.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you were close, closures have a own namespace - so you have to make your variable known:

```
  $pieceId = $options['pieceId'];

   $builder
       ->add('full', FileType::class, [
           'data_class' => null

       ])
      ->add('ordering', EntityType::class, [
          'class' =>Image::class,
           'choice_label' => 'ordering',
           'query_builder' => function (ImageRepository $er) use ($pieceId) {
               return $er->findByPieceAndReturnOrdered($pieceId);

           }
      ])


   ;
```

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Thanks ! But this is where I am still lost... I did that in the first place, still throws the same error. Even my IDE would red-underline the variable...

Comment: You use the getId from the Piece Object which you bind to the form.on a create action your id will always be 0|null - is this the error? then you would need to use form listeners like shown in https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#customizing-your-form-based-on-the-underlying-data

Comment: Well the getId seems to populate the variable alright at controller level. The error is that the form does not accept it as an option, as I can't manage to define it as a form option, thus calls it '0' or any index I assign the variable to in the controller. I guess the issue is that I can't set the configureOptions() method to properly define my custom form option. Either this, or the variable is not properly sent from the controller, but the dumps seem to say otherwise.